# cannot convert ‘std::vector<double>*’ to ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<double*>, double*>::value_type’ {aka ‘double*’}

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I can't convert the double to double here
in main.h I have :

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> *m_va;

std::vector<std::vector<double> > *get_ptr() { return m_va; }
```

in main.cpp I want to have :

```
std::vector<double *> F(n);

F[i] = this->get_ptr()[j].data();
```

but I got :
cannot convert ‘std::vector*’ to ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<double*, double*>::value_type’ {aka ‘double*’}

Comment: `get_ptr()` returns `std::vector<std::vector<double> >* `. `get_ptr()[j]` returns `std::vector<std::vector<double> >`. `get_ptr()[j].data()` returns `std::vector<double>`. `std::vector<double>` can't be assigned to `F[i]` that is `double*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful when mixing C and C++ approaches.

A `std::vector` is an object and you cannot treat the pointer to that object as if it was the pointer to the underlying buffer.

Your `get_ptr()` method returns a pointer to a vector not a vector itself or a reference to it, as a consequence the brackets are **not** mapped as a call to `operator[]` of `*m_va`, but as `*(m_va + j)` instead (which probably results in undefined behavior in your case).

Then calling `data()` on the `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` assumed to exist at that location would return a pointer to the beginning of the underlying buffer, where the content is of type `std::vector<double>`(thus this pointer is of type `std::vector<double>*` that's why you get that compile error).

```
F[i] = (*(this->get_ptr()))[j].data();
```

would resolve problem, this is equivalent to

```
F[i] = this->get_ptr()->operator[](j).data();
```

Just as personal suggestion, be aware of what you are doing, you are storing raw pointers held by a STL container in another object, if a reallocation occurs in any of the elements of `*m_va` the content of `F` becomes invalid.